# Can i get the ips of all hosts in inventory file while running playbook with --limit flag?

Tags: ansible, iptables, ansible-inventory

I am trying to apply iptable rules to a set of hosts, where I want all the ports to be open for hosts in a particular group.
But I cannot run this recipe for all the hosts together in production environment. So I am using --limit flag to run the playbook. 
But it fails by giving below error:

```
fatal: [test-vm1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'ansible_default_ipv4'"}
```

**inventory-file**

```
[all]

test-vm1  ansible_ssh_host=10.x.x.x
test-vm2  ansible_ssh_host=10.x.x.x
test-vm3  ansible_ssh_host=10.x.x.x
```

**my-playbook.yml**

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  gather_facts: yes
  roles:
    - iptables
```

**rules-list.j2**

```
#Allow communication within hosts in a group
{% for host in groups['all'] %}
iptables -A INPUT -s {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }} -j ACCEPT
{% endfor %}
```

**roles/iptables/tasks/main.yml**

```
- name: Prepare iptables rules
  template: dest='/etc/sysconfig/iptable-config' src=rules-list.j2 owner=root group=root mode=0744
  notify: save iptables rules
```

The command I am trying to run is-

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory-file my-playbook.yml --limit test-vm1
```

If i run the above command withou limit flag, it runs fine without failing i.e.

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory-file my-playbook.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your template loops over `groups[all]` hosts and that includes ALL the hosts, not just the limited ones.
And because you are limiting to some hosts, ansible doesnt gather facts for the rest and your template fails to find the ipv4 for the rest of the hosts.

Have you tried `ansible_play_batch` or `ansible_play_hosts` ?
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html

Comment: I want to run the rules for particular set of hosts, using --limit flag. In my inventory i have intentionally kept the hosts under groups[all], as I want to loop over all the hosts to collect their ip/DNS name to allow traffic for all those ips. 
I was able to achieve this using hostvars[host]['ansible_ssh_host'] raher than  hostvars[host]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'].
I think to get the ipv4 address ansible has to ssh into that particular host, which I have limited to only 1 host, but ansible_ssh_host value is saved in the host_vars while scanning the inventory file.